# E-mailing users to extended permission e-mail

Tags: facebook, email, permissions

I've gathered a ton of e-mail addresses with my Facebook apps, and I'm wondering, can I freely send e-mails relevant to my app (and maybe a relevant offer) to these addresses? (Offcourse in compliance with local spam laws)

According to this page it is: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/355/

But that page is rather outdated.

What are the do's and dont's as of now?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

have a spf record and dk/dkim sign for your domain.

follow the rate limit mean x mails/hour for high frequency mails are usually delivered in spam/junk folder.